# listen for focus/blur on nsiWindowWatcher or nsiWindowMediator? for firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xpcom

I would like to find out whether or not the main browser window is focused. Is this possible to achieve using nsiWindowWatcher or nsiWindowMediator? Been trying to digging Mozilla's documentation with no luck so far..

Firefox addon/jetpack is not an option though

Comment: There is no "main browser window". Users are free to open as many windows as they please, each with as many tabs as they please. This became more common again since private browsing windows were implemented. Can you clarify your question please? Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: Basically I am implementing an extension that needs to check if the current firefox window is focus or not because I don't want the extension to continue running if I switched to other application while running Firefox. The problem is the Mozilla documentation is such a maze and I have no idea how to navigate them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind turns out `addEventListener('focus'/'blur')` on the main js file works fine